# Hide Document Library Name column using JSLink in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, document-library, jslink

How can we hide the document library column title called 'Name'  using JSLink? `I would still like it to display the contents`

Tried the solution `Amal Hashim`, there is some space issue in the library

```
Before js link the display of library
```

[image]

After the jsLink

[image]

Comment: Just don't include it in your view to begin with, although in either case, it will make it difficult to interact with the document for your users, I'd make sure this is absolutely required to exclude it as it really messes with the user experience.

Comment: my bad, just update the question

Answer (score 2):

You can hide a field using JSLink as below

```
(function () {
    var context = {};
    context.Templates = {};
    context.OnPostRender = hideFields;
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(context);
})();

function hideFields(ctx) { 
    var cell = $("div [name='Name']").closest('th'); 
    var cellIndex = cell[0].cellIndex + 1; 
    //$('td:nth-child(' + cellIndex + ')').hide(); 
    $('th:nth-child(' + cellIndex + ')').hide(); 
}
```

Comment: i updated the question, can we make it so it hides only the title and not the content underneath

Comment: Just remove or comment the line as in the updated answer

Comment: it works fine.., but then there is some additional space generated...please see my updates in question

Comment: That happens when the th count doesn't match the td count of the body. Try `$('th:nth-child(' + cellIndex + ') > *').hide();`

Comment: @Mx. we are just hiding not removing.. won't the count stays the same?

Comment: I think you can replace the 'Name' to ' ' (space) to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a CSR that doesn't require jQuery and has no spacing issues:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {
  function init() {
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
       OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
         //document.querySelectorAll("[name=LinkFilenameNoMenu]")[0].parentNode.innerHTML = "<th>"
         //document.querySelectorAll("[name=LinkFilename]")[0].parentNode.innerHTML = "<th>"
         //document.querySelectorAll("[name=FileLeafRef]")[0].parentNode.innerHTML = "<th>"
       },
    });
  }
  RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("~siteCollection/Style Library/hidenamecolumnheading.js"), init);
  init();
});
```

There are 3 OOTB columns called name (internal names: FileLeafRef, LinkFilenameNoMenu, LinkFilename), uncomment the one that you want to hide.

You might also want to change the URL in the RegisterModuleInit function.

Comment: Hi Daniel thanks for the answer, we want the flexibility of having the code in JSLink, it seems like here the url to the .js file is in the code not outside

Comment: The URL in the script is necessary if Minimal Download Strategy is activated on your site. Without that part or with a wrong URL the script wouldn't work correctly with MDS.